# Can you put if else statements into notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I am currently trying to do a project for school and i want to put an if else statement in

I do not really know how to do this and any response would be of help
thanks

Comment: Could you explain clearly what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ is only a text editor. Any text you type in yourself will be written to the document you are working on.

So if you want to write an if, else statement, use your keyboard and type it in.

Notepad++ has syntax hilighting but auto inserts of commands is limited to autocomplete on the current word only. It will suggest the placements of brackets, but for full featured if groups, either create a macro that types the text for you, or switch to an actual development environment that supports this.

Notepad++ does not support the feature of writing if, press a key and get a complete if block automatically inserted into your document such as:

```
if ( )
{
    # your code here
}
else
{
    # your code here
}
```

But you can record a macro, type all above in manually once, bind that macro to a key, and insert that if block by the press of a keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ is a text editor and you can enter any text there, including your IF-THEN-ELSE.

However, that will just remain lying there and will not get executed if you want your IF-THEN-ELSE to be executed as it does in a programming language or in macro.

To execute something, PythonScript plugin of npp needs to be installed, and then you have to write script to get your command(s) executed. That has an entire syllabus of its own.